# Talend ESB : How to write the rejected data into database when XML failed against a XSD

Tags: talend, esb

Please shed some light or examples or screen print for the below scenarios?

1. Incoming XML will be validated against XSD
2. When validation is passed, valid message details will be inserts into the central database table
3. When validation is failed, invalid message details will be inserts into a Failure database table.

Best Regards,
Sam

Comment: Which palette are you using ? Mediation component or Data Integration components ?

Comment: In Mediation we do not have a component to validate the XML using XSD. Using cTalendJob that goes to DI job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using DI components, with the tXSDValidator, you can use 'flow mode' to get access to reject links : then you can use OK or KO links to push data to your DB.

Another option: in Mediation perspective you can use a cMessagingEndpoint to use 'validator' pattern : https://camel.apache.org/validation.html . You can use a cTry before this component to retrieve rejects.